# Display local images ends in "Unknown named module" in React Native

Tags: react-native

I try to dynamically display a list of local images, which are stored in the folder .img/. React Native throws the error „Unknown named module: ‚./img/a1.jpg‘ with my implementation. I read about the problem of dynamically requiring images, but wasn’t able to solve the problem. Do you have any suggestions?

```
export class ImageList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    const datav2 = [
        "./img/a1.jpg",
        "./img/a6.jpg"
    ];
    const lapsList = datav2.map((data) => {
      var testPath = require(data);
      return (
        <View>
          <Image source={testPath} style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "#33ff00"}} />
        </View>
      )
    })
    return (
      <View>
        {lapsList}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the dynamic loading by adding `require` directly inside your array.

```
render() {
  const datav2 = [
    require("./img/a1.jpg"),
    require("./img/a6.jpg"),
  ];
  const lapsList = datav2.map((data) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={data} style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "#33ff00"}} />
      </View>
    )
  })
  return (
    <View>
      {lapsList}
    </View>
  );
}
```

In addition, you should move `datav2` outside the `render()` method to not require images on each render.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should add require in the array and then put the datav2 variable outside `render()` , don't forget to add the `index` in the array map to be `key` in the view return so there is no warning in your apps, like this :

```
const datav2 = [
  require("./img/a1.jpg"),
  require("./img/a6.jpg"),
];

export class ImageList extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
   super();
 }

 render() {

   const lapsList = datav2.map((data,i) => {
     return (
        <View key={i}>
          <Image source={testPath} style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "#33ff00"}} />
        </View>
     )
   })

   return (
    <View>
      {lapsList}
    </View>
   );

  }
}
```

And this is the result example when i try it on my emulator :

[image]

I hope this answer can help you :)

Comment: Index as key is an anti-pattern.